# How to avoid loadIntent() get fired each time on fragment start

Tags: mosby

When using mosby-mvi,

Following code works fine -- fired only once when fragment created.

```
override fun loadIntent(): Observable<Unit> {
    return Observable.just(Unit)
}
```

Following code works unexpected -- fired each time the activity wake up from background.

```
override fun loadIntent(): Observable<Unit> {
    return Observable.just(Unit).mergeWith(RxView.clicks(error).map { Unit })
}
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

That is RxJava's contract that Mosby respects.

In the first example what happens is the following:

```
override fun loadIntent(): Observable<Unit> {
  return Observable.just(Unit)
}
```

Then in the presenter presenter you do something like:

```
intent(YourView::loadIntent)
```

This basically subscribes to `loadIntent()` which is `Observable.just(Unit)`

Then the following RxJava callbacks are triggered inside `intent(YourView::loadIntent)`:

```
--> onNext(Unit)
--> onComplete()
```

So your `intent(YourView::loadIntent)` reached the `onComplete()` state which means any future emissions will be just ignored (that is the RxJava contract).
So the "magic" why this intent only triggers is because in your presenter it reaches `onComplete()`.

In the second example:

```
override fun loadIntent(): Observable<Unit> {
    return Observable.just(Unit).mergeWith(RxView.clicks(error).map { Unit })
}
```

The thing to notice here `mergeWith()` operator. The "problem" here is that `mergeWith()` only completes (and calls `onComplete()`) if both `Observable.just(Unit)` and `RxView.clicks(error)` individually reach `onComplete`. While `Observable.just(Unit)` reaches onComplete() as already discussed in the previous code snipped, `RxView.clicks(error)` never reaches `onComplete()` and that is why `mergeWith()` never reaches `onComplete()` and that is why on Fragment recreation (like screen orientation change) this intent triggers again.

I would recommend to do the `mergeWith()` in your presenter and split it in two intents: `loadIntnent()` and `retryLoadingOnErrorIntent()`.